# Artin Algebra 5.7.6

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was thinking about this problem but could not come up with any normal example. I was trying to crack with some playing with some number theory, like gcd, lcm but could not solve it. I am interested only in b) part.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Take for example $G:=S_3, H=\langle (12) \rangle, K=\langle (23)\rangle$. Then $H \cap K=\{id\}$, so $[H:H \cap K] =2$ and $[G:K]=6/2=3$.

Remark: The point is that this example works because $H,K$ are not normal subgroups of $G$, otherwise - if e.g. $K$ is normal - we have $[H:K \cap H]=[HK:K] $ divides $[G:K]$ by an isomorphism theorem